# Anyone know what a replacement Disc pads might be for Tektro HD-R290?

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, compatibility, brake-pads, tektro

The brake pads say F10BS but they've been really hard to find (and unavailable on Tektro site).  Does Shimano (or anyone else) offer a resin version of this brake pad as this one is metal-ceramic?

[image]

Comment: Lots of brake pads are compatible, a quick search for HD-R290 pads pulled up quite a few options. You need to know wether you can use a resin pad with your rotors before you start using them though.

Comment: @DanK why wouldn't resin pads be an option? the only limitation I know of is 'resin-only' discs

Comment: @Swifty - rotors is another term for discs.

Comment: @mattnz correct

Comment: @DanK why wouldn't resin pads be an option? the only limitation I know of is 'resin-only' rotors

Comment: Anyone find a readily available alternative to the F10BS pads yet?

Answer (score 8):

Tektro has on their website a [Brake pad finder tool](https://tektro-usa.com/brake-pads-finder/).  Entering your brake model number offers several compatible brake pad models.  There are options for both resin/semi-metallic and metallic compounds.  The above linked page has itself a hyperlink to an option of buying pads direct from Tektro.

Yes, Shimano brake pads can also be used.  Your Tektro pad model numbers that can be used with the HD-R290 brakes are E10.11 & A10.11.  Shimano brake pad model numbers that can replace these are B01S and M05.  Tektro's higher performance pad option is model number P20.11 which can be switched out for Shimano's G01A, G02A, GO3S, & G04Ti.   There are a couple other Tektro pad models that can be used with the HD-R290 (see results of the pad finder), however those models aren't listed as having a like Shimano pad.

Comment: I think you are right that it's a form factor copy of G01A etc, but that's a different pad shape "family" then B01S and M05.

Answer (score 2):

Tektro F10BS seem to be unique. I have multiple pads for other bikes, including a bunch of E10.11 pads, and they are NOT the same size. The Tektro HD R290 brakes will not take the slightly bigger pads. Like the OP, I'm also looking for these and have not found a suitable replacement.

Comment: I've also contacted Tektro about their pad finder data and hope to get an update. When I do I will update this post.

Comment: did you ever get an update from Tektro ?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Shimano K03S or Swisstop Disc 34.

The HD-R290 brakes spec sheet [does not indicate](https://www.tektro.com/products.php?p=260) the pad to use - except that it must be resin, but finding subsitutes to the F10BS is possible.

According to [Tektro website](http://tektro.com/products.php?p=228), F10BS are meant for HD-R310/R510 calipers. The [compatibility chart](https://www.tektro.com/upload/Product/F_20170613131999DtkdK8.PDF) on Tektro's site also states that the equivalent of these pads are Shimano K02S (resin, predecessor of K03S) and K04S (metal, excluded as indicated by the spec sheet).

Swisstop also indicates that they sell a brake pad compatible with these calipers: the [Disc 34](https://www.swissstop.ch/brakepads/discbrakes/disc34/disc-rs/) (different variants, RS depicted here).

Note that I found a page that makes an explicit link between HD290 and the pads that I mentioned: the [Cowboy 3](https://cowboy.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/pdf/Cowboy3_User_Manual.pdf) user manual, where the following is written:

> The brake pads used on Cowboy bikes are the TEKTRO F10BS/F10XS but
> compatible pads include:
>
> - TEKTRO HD-R290 brake pads
> - Shimano K03S resin brake